# The range of a twisted composition of sines

Tags: limits, functions

Let $f(x) = \sin \left( \frac \pi 6 \sin \left( \frac \pi 2\sin x \right) \right)$ and $g(x) = \frac \pi 2 \sin x$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Which of the following are true?

1. The range of $f$ is $[-0.5,0.5]$
2. The range of $f \circ g$ is $[-0.5,0.5]$
3. $\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)} = \frac \pi 6$
4. There is a $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $g(f(x))=1$.

I think for option 3 we need to go for the Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ but the problem is I couldn't even start with the question. Hope you guys help. Thanks!

Comment: As $-1≤\sin (\theta)≤1$ we see that the entire range of $f(x)$ is confined between $\sin(-\frac {\pi}6)$ and  $\sin(\frac {\pi}6)$

Comment: In my opinion "Very hard question on functions." seems very unpolite

Comment: So what should I right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$, we have that $-\frac \pi 2 \le \frac \pi 2 \sin x \le \frac \pi 2$, so when we apply $\sin$ again we get

   $$-1 \le \sin \left( \frac \pi 2 \sin x \right) \le 1 ,$$

   so

   $$-\frac \pi 6 \le \frac \pi 6 \sin \left( \frac \pi 2 \sin x \right) \le \frac \pi 6 ,$$

   and if we apply $\sin$ once more we get

   $$-\frac 1 2 = \sin \left(-\frac \pi 6 \right) \le \sin \left( \frac \pi 6 \sin \left( \frac \pi 2 \sin x \right) \right) \le \sin \frac \pi 6 = \frac 1 2 ,$$

   so the range of $f$ is a *subset* of $\left[-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2 \right]$. On the other hand, $f$ is a composition of surjective functions, so $\left[-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2 \right]$ is in fact the full range of $f$.
2. Like 1., with an extra $\sin$.
3. $$\lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)} = \lim \limits _{x \to 0} \frac {\sin \left( \frac \pi 6 \sin \left( \color {blue} {\frac \pi 2 \sin x} \right) \right)} {\color {blue} {\underbrace {\frac \pi 2 \sin x} _t} } = \lim \limits _{t \to 0} \frac {\sin \left( \frac \pi 6 \sin t \right)} t = \\ \lim \limits _{t \to 0} \frac {\sin \left( \color {blue} {\frac \pi 6 \sin t} \right)} {\color {blue} {\underbrace {\frac \pi 6 \sin t} _u}} \cdot \frac {\frac \pi 6 \sin t} t = \lim \limits _{u \to 0} \frac {\sin u} u  \cdot \frac \pi 6 \lim \limits _{t \to 0} \frac {\sin t} t = \frac \pi 6 .$$
4. Since $f : \Bbb R \to \left[ -\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2 \right]$ is surjective (proved above) and $g : \Bbb R \to \left[ -\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2 \right]$ is surjective too (because $\sin : \Bbb R \to [-1, 1]$ is), then $g \circ f : \Bbb R \to \left[ -\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2 \right]$ will also be surjective (because function composition preserves surjectivity); since $1 \in \left[ -\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2 \right]$, there exist $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $(g \circ f) (x) = 1$.